# Struct error with PIL exif when saving image - how to except this error?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I am opening images with PIL, reading their exif information, compressing the image to the allowed_size, and adding the exif back to the image when I Image.save it. After about 3,000 successes with this process, a file gave me the following struct.error:

'struct.error: 'H' format requires 0 <= number <= 65535'

The struct.error is thrown at img.save step in my (simplified) code here:

```
from PIL import Image,ExifTags

allowed_size = 123456 #Some Number
fname = 'path/to/file.type'
file_size = os.path.getsize(fname)
new_fname = #secret string

img = Image.open(fname)
exif = img.getexif()
len_exif = len(exif)
if(len_exif >0):
   if file_size > upload_size:
      img.save(new_fname,"JPEG", optimize=True, quality=100,exif=exif) #Decompress first, better for predicting quality value needed for target file size
      #Do other things, resize
```

I gather that this is an error potentially due to the exif read from the original image being incorrect to what PIL is expecting. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

**The question**: how do I go about doing a try: and except: with this error? I would like to try saving the file after compression with the exif information and if this struct.error presents itself to skip adding the exif back and just save the file.

**Thank you in advance for any pointers. **What am I missing? Is the exception for this struct.error possible? I'm new to posting here, but I have been reading for years. Please accept my apologies if you need more information to weigh in of if this question is below the standards of the site.

I've tried this:

```
try:
   img.save(new_fname,"JPEG", optimize=True, quality=100,exif=exif)
except struct.error:
   img.save(new_fname,"JPEG", optimize=True, quality=100)
```

Expecting an exception and the file to save without exif, but got 'NameError: name 'struct' is not defined.'

Python 3.11

Comment: Add `import struct` at the top of your script and see if that works.  `struct` is part of the standard library, and is imported by parts of Pillow.  In `PIL.JpegImagePlugin.py`, there is a comment indicating `  # struct.error for truncated EXIF`   If you post the full traceback it may be possible to determine exactly which data element is missing or exceeds the `int_16` range and correct it in the file data.

Comment: Thanks! I added the import and the exception worked as expected. I didn't save the full error, unfortunately, but if I can get it to do this again I'll post back